# Deploying my rails app on a vps using Passenger and Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, deployment, passenger

I followed this walkthrough (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/apache/oss/el6/deploy_app.html) in deploying my rails app using Passenger but when I try to go to the ip address on my browser, I get a 'This site cannot be reached' error. I had the same problem using Nginx and I switched to Apachebut Im still having the same issue. This is my first deployment and Im really confused right now. Any help will be appreciated. Here's my /etc/httpd/conf.d/cfkmv.conf if it helps

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 144.217.160.59
     # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
     DocumentRoot /var/www/my_fast_cash/code/public

     PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/wrappers/ruby

     # Relax Apache security settings
     <Directory /var/www/my_fast_cash/code/public>
         Allow from all
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         #Require all granted
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: remove /code from 'Document root and Directory' and restart server may works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Install passenger and add passenger module in .conf file

Command to install passenger:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

After installation, they provide code of module installation so add it under your server conf file then restart it.

Code is something like that:

```
 LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.59/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.59
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>
```